# Spring WebClient Preferred HttpClient Library?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

Spring Webclient supports 3 HttpClient libraries - Reactor Netty, Jetty Rective Http Client, and Apache Http Components .

Which is the most recommended one and in what circumstances?

Comment: Reactor Netty is the default, thus, the most widely used/supported. AFAIK it is developed by the company behind Spring. Unless you have some special requirements, it's best to start with Reactor Netty.